# WooCommerce products shortcode how to display products if all of the categories match

Tags: woocommerce, categories, shortcode, wordpress-shortcode, woocommerce-theming

I am trying to understand how I can make a page show certain products if ALL of the categories match. So for instance, if the page has this code

```
[products limit="16" columns ="4" category="interior,lighting"]
```

I would want it to only show products that have both the interior and lighting category specified. Right now, this means that either of these categories will show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `cat_operator` as part of your shortcode and `AND` relationship, like so:

```php
[products limit="16" columns ="4" category="interior,lighting" cat_operator="AND"]
```

You could read more about it on the documentation page:

[Woocommerce shortcodes](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/)